# Trouble calling a SQL function with a custom table type parameter using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL Scalar-valued function which takes a custom table type as its only parameter.  This table type parameter is a single column of integers.  The SQL function computes the median of the dataset and returns the resultant integer.

I have a dashboard in my web forms web application (written in C#) which displays some fun metrics.  Currently, I have an IQueryable of my custom datatype which gets filtered down, then I am forced to enumerate the entire integer column I want to get the median of.  Currently, I have a local function which takes an IEnumerable and returns an integer which is the median.

My issue is that enumerating the IQueryable to compute the median is pulling upwards of hundreds of thousands of records in total and causing performance issues caused by the excess SQL traffic.  I want to use my SQL function to compute the median of the IQueryable on the SQL-side to mitigate this issue.   Since the function takes a custom table type, I am at a loss of how to get this to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK custom table types only have are handled via the .NET SQL client through the ADO.NET datable, so you would need to call your function with a datatable as param, the ienumerable won't cut it.